# Inner classes (Android) not in camelcase?

Tags: android

```
public final class R {

    public static final class id {
        public static final int menu_settings=0x7f080000;
    }
    public static final class layout {
        public static final int activity_main=0x7f030000;
    }
    public static final class menu {
        public static final int activity_main=0x7f070000;
    }
    public static final class string {
        public static final int app_name=0x7f050000;
        public static final int hello_world=0x7f050001;
        public static final int menu_settings=0x7f050002;
        public static final int title_activity_main=0x7f050003;
    }

}
```

I don´t understand why those inner classes are not CamelCased?

Is there a resaon they do it like this ?

Comment: And constants should be also UPPERCASEd...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the reason that those are not camel-cased is because Google wanted the way we reference those in code and name the xml files to be the same, and the xml files have to be all lower cased (this is probably for consistency matching other build files and resources).

Therefore we create string.xml and we refer to it R.string.*_*

Comment: Yes...I thought it was something like that.
I can understand the logic behind it now.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe to give the impression that you are calling fields `R.id.xxxx`?
And `string` could not be in camel case anyway as the name is already taken.